# CosmosDB Trigger is not working with WebJobs

Tags: azure-webjobs, c#-6.0, cosmosdbtrigger

I have `CosmosDBTrigger` on my 3 `WebJobs` which is targeting the same container. Meaning, whenever any `Upsert` happens on this container, these 3 should be triggered. I am seeing the issue where 1 out of 3 job is not triggering and trying to understand why.

I manually disabled these jobs for debug purpose where I hit the break point for `WebJob2` and `WebJob3`. When I do the same for `WebJob1` then nothing happens.

This is how `CosmosDBTrigger` is defined on jobs. If 2 jobs are triggering, then logic seems good to me. Here, `WebJob1` is not triggering. What am I missing here?

WebJob1:

```
public async Task ProcessMessageAsync(
    [CosmosDBTrigger(
      "%Database:DatabaseName%", 
      "%Database:ContainerName%", 
      Connection = CosmosDbConnectionString, 
      CreateLeaseContainerIfNotExists = true, 
      LeaseContainerName = "leases", 
      LeaseContainerPrefix = nameof(WebJob1)
    )]
      string documents, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  // Logic
}
```

WebJob2:

```
public async Task ProcessMessageAsync(
    [CosmosDBTrigger(
      "%Database:DatabaseName%", 
      "%Database:ContainerName%", 
      Connection = CosmosDbConnectionString, 
      CreateLeaseContainerIfNotExists = true, 
      LeaseContainerName = "leases", 
      LeaseContainerPrefix = nameof(WebJob2)
    )]
      string documents, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  // Logic
}
```

WebJob3:

```
public async Task ProcessMessageAsync(
    [CosmosDBTrigger(
      "%Database:DatabaseName%", 
      "%Database:ContainerName%", 
      Connection = CosmosDbConnectionString, 
      CreateLeaseContainerIfNotExists = true, 
      LeaseContainerName = "leases", 
      LeaseContainerPrefix = nameof(WebJob3)
    )]
      string documents, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  // Logic
}
```

Comment: Theory which fixed this issue: This was due to manually adding or deleting entries in lease container, which corrupted it and caused job's pointer misaligned. Redeployment of the ARM template for cosmos fixed this issue.

Comment: Please post your sol as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Theory which fixed this issue: This was due to manually adding or deleting entries in lease container, which corrupted it and caused job's pointer misaligned. Redeployment of the ARM template for cosmos fixed this issue.